# Can't render html in Wicket

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, wicket

Let's consider I have a HTML markup:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="ico ico-prev"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown2 inline">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-shorter">
            <strong>1-8</strong>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu spec_width">
            <li><a data-ico="1" href="#">10-30</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">30-40</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">40-50</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">50-60</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <i class="ico ico-next"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<span class="page-title">from<strong>45</strong></span>

.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: -1px;
    top: 37px;
    font-size: 13px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #d1d4d3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.dropdown-menu li > a {
    color: #4d5357;
    padding: 8px 20px;
}
.spec_width {
    width: 72px;
    min-width: 72px;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin-left: -36px;
    max-height: 150px;
    min-height: 30px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.spec_width li {
    line-height: 29px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
padding: 4px 0;
}

.spec_width li:hover {
    background: #e1e1e1;
}

.spec_width li a {
    padding: 0px 0;
    background: none !important;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I use that markup in ModalWindow, and it works pretty good, but when I apply CSS class to `<ul>` tag I don't see it in the browser, but when I inspect element, it generates in HTML code. I think that it must be because I use it in ModalWindow, and something(script, style) is conflicted. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to post the css for this html snippet as well. First guess: `.dropdown-menu` is hidden with `display: none;` or `visiblity: hidden; opacity:0;` by default.

Comment: How are we supposed to help without seeing said CSS? We're programmers, not psychics!

Comment: @NicoO I beg you pardon, right now I don't have .css file. But that markup works well, when I launch it as .html file in browser. That's problem of Wicket's ModalWindow.

Comment: @RUJordan, I edited my question, and added .CSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Wicket to create HTML emails, we need to fake the request/response cycle. I wrote this convenient method that renders a bookmarkable page (pageclass + pageparameters) to a string:
http://www.danwalmsley.com/render_a_wicket_page_to_a_string_for_html_email

> protected String renderPage(Class extends Page> pageClass,
>   PageParameters pageParameters) {
>
> ```
>   //get the servlet context       WebApplication application =
> ```
>
> (WebApplication) WebApplication.get();
>
> ```
>   ServletContext context = application.getServletContext();
>
>   //fake a request/response cycle         MockHttpSession servletSession =
> ```
>
> new MockHttpSession(context);         servletSession.setTemporary(true);
>
> ```
>   MockHttpServletRequest servletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest(
>           application, servletSession, context);      MockHttpServletResponse servletResponse = new MockHttpServletResponse(
>           servletRequest);
>
>   //initialize request and response       servletRequest.initialize();
>   servletResponse.initialize();
>
>   WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(servletRequest);
>
>   BufferedWebResponse webResponse = new
> ```
>
> BufferedWebResponse(servletResponse);         webResponse.setAjax(true);
>
> ```
>   WebRequestCycle requestCycle = new WebRequestCycle(
>           application, webRequest, webResponse);
>
>   requestCycle.setRequestTarget(new
> ```
>
> BookmarkablePageRequestTarget(pageClass, pageParameters));
>
> ```
>   try {           requestCycle.request();
>
>       log.warn("Response after request: "+webResponse.toString());
>
>       if (requestCycle.wasHandled() == false) {
>           requestCycle.setRequestTarget(new WebErrorCodeResponseTarget(
>                   HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND));             }           requestCycle.detach();
>
>   } finally {             requestCycle.getResponse().close();         }       return
> ```
>
> webResponse.toString();

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I append `target.appendJavaScript("launchJS();");` where I had `AjaxRequestTarget` in my pages.